# Session Token Authentication perl in cookie

Tags: encryption, token, access-token

I am working session authentication. I am passing session id as token in cookie header. I wish to get encrypted token. which cryptable method should i prefer. I am using Digest::SHA, i got this error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message:
Attempt to reload Digest/SHA1.pm aborted. Compilation failed in require at /opt/lampp/htdocs/cts/login.pl line 21. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/lampp/htdocs/cts/login.pl line 21. 
 what should do to overcome this error? Otherwise shall i use another one?

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging your code. Take it through step by step, and look at the value of each variable. That might give you some insight, or at least give you a more specific understanding of why the program is failing to load. From the question you've given to us here, you really aren't giving us much to go off :)